# UIButton in UITableViewCell crashes when clicked

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

This should be simple, but I can't figure out what's wrong.  I'm creating a tableview and I want a button that I can click to switch between checked and unchecked:

```
    UITableViewCell *cell;
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DiaperCellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                   reuseIdentifier:DiaperCellIdentifier] autorelease];
        wetButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked_large.png"];
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(150.0, 5.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        wetButton.frame = frame;
        [wetButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
        [wetButton addTarget:self action:@selector(wetClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:wetButton];
```

Now when I click this button, I get a stack trace....[NSCFString scale]: unrecognized selector sent to instance....  thanks for any help.

```
- (void) wetClicked:(id)sender{
if (isWet) {
    isWet = NO;
    [wetButton setBackgroundImage:@"unchecked_large.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else {
    isWet = YES;
    [wetButton setBackgroundImage:@"checked_large.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

}

and here's the trace:

2011-03-09 10:19:57.124 InfantCare[64064:207] -[NSCFString scale]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x33be0

2011-03-09 10:19:57.240 InfantCare[64064:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString scale]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x33be0'

*** Call stack at first throw:

(

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00f2dbe9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x010825c2 objc_exception_throw + 47

2   CoreFoundation                      0x00f2f6fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187

3   CoreFoundation                      0x00e9f366 ___forwarding___ + 966

4   CoreFoundation                      0x00e9ef22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50

5   UIKit                               0x003d1e7b -[UIImageView setImage:] + 250

6   UIKit                               0x004ea353 -[UIButton layoutSubviews] + 273

7   QuartzCore                          0x01d58451 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181

8   QuartzCore                          0x01d5817c CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220

9   QuartzCore                          0x01d5137c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310

10  QuartzCore                          0x01d510d0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292

11  QuartzCore                          0x01d817d5 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99

12  CoreFoundation                      0x00f0efbb __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27

13  CoreFoundation                      0x00ea40e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295

14  CoreFoundation                      0x00e6cbd7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575

15  CoreFoundation                      0x00e6c240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208

16  CoreFoundation                      0x00e6c161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97

17  GraphicsServices                    0x017cf268 GSEventRunModal + 217

18  GraphicsServices                    0x017cf32d GSEventRun + 115

19  UIKit                               0x0031642e UIApplicationMain + 1160

20  InfantCare                          0x00002228 main + 102

21  InfantCare                          0x000021b9 start + 53
```

)

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.

Comment: You do not need to retain the button after it has been added as subview. At least unless you need to access it at some later time. Other than that the code you posted looks ok to me. I think scale is a property of UIImage. If this get's sent to a string you probably have memory leaking somewhere in your code. Did you check the app for leaks with instruments? Also it might be helpful to see the complete stack trace.

Comment: Please post your `wetClicked:` method, the problem is most likely in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use an UIImage instance as a parameter when you call the function setBackgroundImage:

```
[wetButton setBackgroundImage:@"unchecked_large.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

use instead:

```
[wetButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked_large.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Nava, that was it exactly!  Thank you so much!

Comment: I had a similar problem, after reading this, I changed an `imageWithContentsOfFile` into an `imageNamed` and that fixed it.  I guess the `imageWithContentsOfFile` had been autoreleased or something.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have posted is fine. The problem is most likely in your `wetClicked:` method, you are calling the `scale` method on an NSString.

---

Now that you've posted `wetClicked:` and the trace, I see the problem: You're passing a string instead of an image to `setBackgroundImage:forState:`. Try this instead:

```
- (void) wetClicked:(id)sender{
    if (isWet) {
        isWet = NO;
        [wetButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked_large.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        isWet = YES;
        [wetButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_large.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: I've included the method wetClicked: and the trace.  When I have a breakpoint at the beginning of wetClicked, i never get to it before the dump...